# How to proper structure Flutter design

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout

I have stucked with an issue learning Flutter. I take a design from dribbble and try to implement it. The goal is to implement a horizontal scrollable list view but I want it to appear with padding and when I scroll it left it goes over the screen (see attachments). When I scroll left the items of the list should goes over the screen without padding. I tried to add empty sized box as first item of the list but it looks like incorrect approach. I am sure I am doing something wrong and it would be helpful if some one steer me in the right direction. [image: Example of horizontal scrollable list view behavior].

Comment: As a workaround, you can apply the left padding for your first widget in the horizontal list view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView has a padding property you can use that.

```
ListView(
  padding:EdgeInsets.only(left:10),
  ...
),
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.